# PHP echo data to .json file

Tags: php, json, echo

I have a question. I have a php code that echoes data to json objects. 
This is my code:

```
<?php

$host = "localhost"; //Your database host server
$db = "..."; //Your database name
$user = "..."; //Your database user
$pass = "..."; //Your password

$connection = mysql_connect($host, $user, $pass);

//Check to see if we can connect to the server
if(!$connection)
{
    die("Database server connection failed.");  
}
else
{
    //Attempt to select the database
    $dbconnect = mysql_select_db($db, $connection);

    //Check to see if we could select the database
    if(!$dbconnect)
    {
        die("Unable to connect to the specified database!");
    }
    else
    {
        $query = "SELECT * FROM wedstrijden";
        $resultset = mysql_query($query, $connection);

        $records = array();
                    $response = array(); //extra            

        //Loop through all our records and add them to our array
        while($r = mysql_fetch_assoc($resultset))
        {
            $records[] = $r;        
        }

        //Output the data as JSON
        echo json_encode($records);    

    }
} 
?>
```

The result of this is a .php file wich echoes JSON objects. But i want a .json file (like a results.json file) which shows the JSON objects. Is this possible?

Can you help me?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What are you trying to do with the results? Write them to a file, or serve them in an http response?

Comment: Write them to a .json file. Now i have a .php file who echoes it, but i want a .json file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To create / overwrite file use `file_put_contents` function:

```
file_put_contents('url/to/your/file/records.json', json_encode($records), LOCK_EX);
```

To read (output) from php:

```
echo file_get_contents('url/to/your/file/records.json');
```

**Update:**

```
<?php
....
//Check to see if we can connect to the server
if(!$connection)
{
    die("Database server connection failed.");  
}
else
{
    //Attempt to select the database
    $dbconnect = mysql_select_db($db, $connection);

    //Check to see if we could select the database
    if(!$dbconnect)
    {
        die("Unable to connect to the specified database!");
    }
    else
    {
        $query = "SELECT * FROM wedstrijden";
        $resultset = mysql_query($query, $connection);

        $records = array();
        $response = array(); //extra            

        //Loop through all our records and add them to our array
        while($r = mysql_fetch_assoc($resultset))
        {
            $records[] = $r;        
        }

        //Output the data as JSON
        $json = json_encode($records);    

        //NOTE: FOLDERS 'url' and 'file' SHOULD BE WRITABLE WITH PERMISSIONS - 777
        //IN CASE 'url' FOLDER PLACED IN SERVER'S ROOT
        //IF YOU'RE USING SOME FTP BROWSER CHANGE PERMISSIONS FOR 'url' 
        //FOLDER AND APPLY IT TO ALL ENCLOSED ITEMS
        file_put_contents('url/file/records.json', $json);

    }
} 
?>
```

Comment: When i do this (echo file_get_contents('url/results.json');), there is nothing happen in my results.json file. It is still empty.

Comment: @Teddy could you check the 'url/results.json' file it's self?
Does it created?

Comment: it doenst. Maybe i put the file_put_contents(... line on the wrong place? Where i have to write this in my code (see above). Sorry, i'm not very expierenced with php.

Comment: @Teddy check write permissions on the folder where you try to `file_put_contents()` it's should be writable (777)

Comment: Thanks, i changed the permission from url/records.json to 777. But nothing changes. I think i write the file_get_contents or the file_put_contents on the wrong place in my code. Maybe you can say exactly where i have to write these? MANY THANKS FOR YOUR HELP, i really appreciate it!

Comment: @Teddy please see my update on this answer. Note: full route from server's root to folder where your new *.json file will be placed should be writable

Comment: Thanks for your help, but is does not work. My root map (public_html) is on permission 777, and the file records.json is also 777. When i enter my json.php file, i see the next error: Warning: file_put_contents() [function.file-put-contents]: Exclusive locks may only be set for regular files in /home/deb35589/domains/.../public_html/json.php on line 53

Comment: @Teddy try put contents without 'Exclusive lock', like: `file_put_contents('url/file/records.json', $json);`

Comment: Thanks! Now i got this error:  Warning: file_put_contents(http://www..../records.json) [function.file-put-contents]: failed to open stream: HTTP wrapper does not support writeable connections in /home/deb35589/domains/.../public_html/json.php on line 47

Maybe my server doesn't support this? 

(I really appreciate it you help me everytime, i hope you dont get tired of me)

Comment: Okay, google says i have to use a ftp URL to write a file. I try this.

Comment: @Teddy glad to help you, congrats

Answer (score 2):

add json header may helps(before the echo fragment):

```
header("content-type:application/json");
```

Comment: So much better approch. The browser does not care about .php or .json-ending, but the encoding of the file. Using `file_put_contents` could potentially display old and outdated values.

Answer (score 0):

file_put_contents should do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, let's get the `MYSQL` speech out of the way. It's deprecated and should no longer be used, so try `MYSQLI` or one of the `PDO` variants.

Secondly, it sounds like you want one large JSON response. If that's the case, change this bit of code:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM wedstrijden";
$resultset = mysql_query($query, $connection);
$records = array();
$response = array(); //extra            
//Loop through all our records and add them to our array
while($r = mysql_fetch_assoc($resultset))
    {
        $records[] = $r;        
    }
echo json_encode($records)
```

To something more like this:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM wedstrijden";
$resultset = mysql_query($query, $connection);
$records = mysql_fetch_all($resultset);
echo json_encode($records, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
```